# In matlab, how do you get out of the property editor?

Tags: matlab

I know this has to be a stupid question, but sometimes I accidentally get into property editor mode in matlab and for the life of me I can't figure out how to get back to the plain figure.  Please help.  It's incredibly frustrating since I mostly just have to close the figure and plot it all again.

Comment: It actually depends on the version of MATLAB.

Comment: In 2012 you just need to drag the tab related to your figure out of the main figure window. also you can uncheck the property editor in the view menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, I know, annoying. The way I do it is to drag the tab (located just under the toolbar) for the figure out of the Property Editor box. In the image below you can see one tab for Figure 4. This moves the figure to a regular figure window and leaves behind an empty Property editor that can be closed. Alternatively you can click the upward-pointing arrow button in the image below to "undock" the figure (this button may be located elsewhere in Windows or in earlier versions of Matlab). I wish the Property Editor would close automatically when empty ... maybe someone else knows about that.

[image: Property Editor tab]

Edit: More about the [Property Editor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/propertyeditor.html). Unfortunately, calling `propertyeditor('off')` does not work, because it leaves an annoying gray bar at the bottom of the figure. This is equivalent to selecting 'close' from the menu at the top right of the Property Editor docked beneath a figure.

Comment: The button is the same in the Windows version, except being toward the right side of the screen (where the close/minimize/maximize buttons traditionally are kept on Windows).

Comment: Thanks, dragging the thing out works.  Not sure how they expect people to intuitively know to do it that way!  And having to manually kill the dead editor is weird.